# How can I change the color order of lines in geom_line() in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I'd like to change the line color in this plot so that they are in a "natural" or original `RColorBrewer` color order. This code produces the following plot:

```
df <- data_frame(GeoName = rep(LETTERS, 3)) %>% 
    arrange(GeoName) %>% 
    mutate(year = rep(c(2009, 2010, 2011), 26),
           percent_change = sample(seq(-3, 3, .1), 78, T))

#create my color ramp function
YlGnBu <- colorRampPalette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, 'YlGnBu'))


df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(year,
               percent_change,
               group = GeoName,
               # order = GeoName,               <- does not accomplish my goal
               color = GeoName))+
    geom_point(show.legend = F)+
    geom_line(show.legend = F)+
    scale_color_manual(values = YlGnBu(n_distinct(df$GeoName)))+ # color function 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2009, 2010, 2011))+              # from above
    theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
          panel.grid = element_blank(),
          axis.line = element_line(color = 'black'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn `GeoName` into a factor and put its levels into the right order. For example, we can color by the value in year 2009:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- data_frame(GeoName = rep(LETTERS, 3)) %>% 
  arrange(GeoName) %>% 
  mutate(year = rep(c(2009, 2010, 2011), 26),
         percent_change = sample(seq(-3, 3, .1), 78, T))

# here is the change:
df$GeoName <- factor(
                df$GeoName,
                levels = (filter(df, year == 2009) %>%
                  arrange(desc(percent_change)))$GeoName)

#create my color ramp function
YlGnBu <- colorRampPalette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, 'YlGnBu'))


df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year,
             percent_change,
             group = GeoName,
             color = GeoName))+
  geom_point(show.legend = F)+
  geom_line(show.legend = F)+
  scale_color_manual(values = YlGnBu(n_distinct(df$GeoName)))+ # color function 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2009, 2010, 2011))+              # from above
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(color = 'black'))
```

[image]

Because the lines criss-cross, they can only be in the natural order for one year. You need to pick the one that works best for the story you want to tell.